# Which bootloader option should I select to boot into Windows?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

Why do I get many options as below when I dual booted my PC with Ubuntu. To continue with windows which option should I go with?

Comment: Please add a list of the options you get at startup. The more information you provide, the more likely it will be that you get a fitting answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use your arrow keys to navigate to the hilited option that has the word 'windows' with it and press 'enter' on your keyboard. And you get more options since one would be just ubuntu and it comes with its own preferences like 'memory check' and stuff like that. In my case, I also have Windows regular OS and Windows 'pro' which I didn't know I had.